# Function to append specific data into a dictionary

Tags: python

I have a .json file full of song details from Spotify, which is stored in playlists. (Info such as song name, artist, album name).

For example:

```
print(data['playlists'][999]['tracks'][43]['track_name'])
print(data['playlists'][999]['tracks'][43]['artist_name'])
```

returns:

```
Cosmic Angel - Acoustic From Capitol Studios
Grizfolk
```

Some of the data looks like this:

```
 'album_uri': 'spotify:album:3yHHbz0wapmu6xF82vHkCU',
     'duration_ms': 209280,
     'album_name': 'Rewind'},
    {'pos': 93,
     'artist_name': 'Thomas Rhett',
     'track_uri': 'spotify:track:5kNe7PE09d6Kvw5pAsx23n',
     'artist_uri': 'spotify:artist:6x2LnllRG5uGarZMsD4iO8',
     'track_name': 'Die A Happy Man',
     'album_uri': 'spotify:album:4ykbJPI8MPscFzROE8dqLy',
     'duration_ms': 227426,
     'album_name': 'Tangled Up'},
    {'pos': 94,
     'artist_name': 'Thomas Rhett',
     'track_uri': 'spotify:track:4O1CExxinEpKZi3861NlTK',
     'artist_uri': 'spotify:artist:6x2LnllRG5uGarZMsD4iO8',
     'track_name': 'Get Me Some Of That',
     'album_uri': 'spotify:album:2ZHYOFW5giX6a4n5eqTnUB',
     'duration_ms': 187400,
     'album_name': 'It Goes Like This'},
```

I want to create a function to append all the track names and artist names into a dictionary.

I've tried this:

```
def artiname(p,t):
    d = {}
    for i in range(p):
        for j in range(t):
            artist = data['playlists'][p]['tracks'][t]['artist_name']
            d['artist']=artist
            track = data['playlists'][p]['tracks'][t]['track_name']
            d['track']=track
```

However, this only outputs:

```
{'artist': 'Grizfolk'}
```

Instead, I wan to make sure this loops through the entire playlist, ending with a dictionary of length p*t.

Comment: I'm curious why there is even any output if your not printing anything. Please show your exact code, and how you call the function

Comment: Hi Tristan, a dictionary can have only one value for "artist". You are probably after a list of dictionaries, one per song. Also you almost certainly need one for-loop, not two nested ones. Please **edit your question** and include code to show what arguments you call your function with, so we can understand: What are p and t, and why are you taking all the combinations?

Comment: @Alexis Thanks for your help. That's what I was after. I've written this and it works:
(BTW how do I properly show code?)

`song_playlist ={}
for i, n in enumerate(data["playlists"]):
    song_playlist[i] = []
    for m in n["tracks"]:
        song_playlist[i].append(m["track_name"])
def make_songlist(x):
    d = {"playlist": 0, "song": x[0]}
    df = pd.DataFrame(d)
    for n in range(1, len(x)//2):
        d = {"playlist": n, "song": x[n]}
        df2 = pd.DataFrame(d)
        df = df.append(df2, ignore_index = True)
    return df
data=make_songlist(song_playlist)
`

Comment: Hi Tristan, you cannot show blocks of code in comments -- they are meant to be short. If this code is the solution to your question, you can post it as a "self-answer", and accept it to record that your problem has been solved. But you should know that you are misusing the dictionary data structure, it makes no sense to have integers as keys. `song_playlist` should be a list of track lists, not a dictionary of track lists.

Comment: @Alexis Thanks for your help! I'm new to coding and stackoverflow.

Comment: @BhargavRao, I believe the OP posted the answer you deleted as the solution to the question. (Because of my suggestion, see comments above.) It's code-only with no explanation, but in any event it was indeed meant as an answer.